# Portmon - Portmsys.sys not found

Tags: windows-8.1, monitoring, serial-port, sysinternals

I've been wrestling with Sysinternals' *Portmon* utility and am trying to get it working under Windows 8.1 64-bit. Initially it would not start - it gave "Error 2" and exited, as detailed in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356470/sysinternals-portmon-error-2). I have run the compatibility troubleshooter and now have it running in Windows XP SP2 compatibility mode, but the `Capture/Ports` menu item is grayed and no ports are shown (I have both a USB and a motherboard-hosted COM port).

I then found [this post](http://forum.sysinternals.com/portmon-303-trouble_topic27382_page2.html) which detailed a procedure claimed to get it running.  It involves creating a shortcut to start the EXE file with a command-line option `/c` however, when I run it I get this:

[image: PortMon - Can't find PORTMSYS.SYS]

I can't find this file anywhere. It not part of the Sysinternals suite download, and it isn't present anywhere on my system that I can find.

Has anyone met this problem with Portmon?

Comment: Why does your question title say ProcMon? Also, are you using Win8.1 32-bit? PortMon was never updated to support 64-bit Windows.

Comment: @Karam.  It said `ProcMon` because I was low on sleep ;).  (Thanks @Peter for fixing that).  I now realise that the [post I referenced](http://forum.sysinternals.com/portmon-303-trouble_topic27382_page2.html) was almost certainly talking about Win8.1 32-bit, which pretty much answers my question for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not find `portmsys.sys` anywhere to download. It is actually part of `portmon.exe`

The way that many Sysinternals tools work ([Process Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer) and [Process Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor)) work, is that they bring their own driver embedded into the main executable. When the program is started it extracts the driver file from itself and installs it and then uses it to do its thing.

`portmsys.sys` is the driver for Portmon, and on 64-bit Windows it extracts it from itself, but it is unable to install it.

I think you have to live with the fact that it doesn't work on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Thanks @Peter.  It would be helpful if the error message had said as much.